# Data binding to an object

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to bind an object to a vue comonent. My object has getters and setters. Each object's value is rendered into a textbox. I need Vue to communicate with object's getter and setter.

Object's structure:

```
Collection: {
    Columns: ['a','b','c'...]
    , Items: [
        Object: {
            Values: ['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3'...]
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

and Vue code looks like

```
<!--<b>data refers to Collection.Items</b>-->
<tr v-for="i in data">
    <!--<b>columns refers to Collection.columns</b>-->
    <!--<td v-for="j in columns"><input type="text" :value="getValue(i,j)" @input="function(e){ setValue(i,j,(e.target||e.srcElement).value); }"/></td>-->
    <td v-for="j in columns"><input type="text" v-model="val(i,j)"/></td>
</tr>
```

Code:

```
   //o refers to an object in Collection.Items
   //k refers to a key in Collection.Columns
   //o.getValue returns value from 
   , methods: { //Working with commented td
        getValue: function(o, k){
            return o.getValue(k);
        }
        , setValue: function(o, k, v){
            o.setValue(k, v);
        }
    }
    , computed: {
        val: function(){ //Working with uncommented td
            return function(o,k){
                return o.getValue(k);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have found a workaround using *:value* and *@value* (commented td)

https://jsfiddle.net/jdtadlock/z11fe07p/981/

but what i would prefer to use is *v-model* and *computed*. (uncommented td) v-model works perfectly, when Vue retrieves value from an object. But when Vue updates changed value back to the object, I get an error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

I guess this is because I did not register any setter.

Question: How I register parametrized setter in computed?

[jsfiddle of a whole project](https://jsfiddle.net/Painkiller/9tz4e5w6/1/)

Comment: Why you need computed property, you can hook variable from array this way `v-model="Collection.column[j]"`

Comment: Object have IsDirty property which is updated if value is changed. I would like to send only dirty rows to server. IsDirty is not updated if i use Your approach without `@value="my function that notifies change"`

Comment: then add `@change="()=>Collection.column[j].isDirty = true"`

Comment: Thank You Deda, but I am trying to keep the template as readable as possible.
If Vue provides chance to do
`, computed: {
 val: function(){
  return function(o,k){
   return o.getValue(k);
  }
 }
}
` to use parametrized getter i hope there is same thing for a setter which i haven't found yet.